# Pip network error (and I am not using a proxy!)

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I often get the infamous pip network error:

```
$ pip3 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
...
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

It works sometimes, most often it does not. I have to try many, many times until I get something installed.

Unlike the many people who have reported similar problems, I am not behind a proxy and I have already tried different networks, both physically and using VPN.

I think the problem is that https://pypi.org/ is *often* unavailable for me. Most of the time, I cannot access the website.

[image]

I don't know if this is country-specific (Portugal here), but other colleagues of mine have similar problems.

A lot of people say to download `get-pip.py` from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and install pip manually. But that website is down as well. I have managed to download `get-pip.py` from somewhere else, but then I get the same pypi error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is [a known issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5374) affecting a Portuguese ISP company. This company doesn't handle well the IPv6 protocol, and pip gives an error. Disabling IPv6 fixes the problem.

In Linux, IPv6 can be temporarily disabled by doing `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`.